# How to know what submit button the user clicked?

Tags: forms, options

I'm working on my settings page, I want to add two different buttons to the form and do something different depending which the user clicked.

The documentation states I can create two buttons like this:

```
submit_button('Submit', 'primary large', 'primary', false);
submit_button( 'Delete', 'delete', 'delete', false );
```

However I don't understand how to differenciate when the user clicked each one, it seems that no matter which button clicked the form is submitted the same.

How can I do something different depending what button the user clicks?

Answer (score 2):

The `submit_button()` function is a wrapper for [`get_submit_button()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_submit_button/). Now that function has multiple arguments, but the most interesting for your actual problem is the 3rd argument `name`. It sets the HTML `name` attribute.

```
<form action="">
    <input ... etc.
    <button type="submit" name="choice-a">
</form>
```

Now everytime you process your form with an empty `action` attribute, you will point to the current request `http://example.com/wp-admin/example.php`. There you will be able to fetch your arguments via the *super globals* `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` (which simplified is mostly a combination of `$_GET` and `$_POST`).

Then just inspect the array and do whatever you need/want to do.

Comment: hi @kaiser I could get the $_POST on the page by removing the action attribute, however I just tried it and the form stops working since it doesn't go to options.php. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: use `<form action="/options.php" type="post">`

Comment: @LisandroVaccaro You maybe should update the code in your question and show your full example and what you really are trying to do. Hint: There's the "Settings API" built in.

Comment: @Bysander Use `esc_url( admin_url( 'options.php' ) );` instead :)

Comment: Hey @kaiser - oh OK - what's the difference to using that - i use `/` all the time to make it easy merging between local & online code

Comment: @Bysander `/` just points to the current request and is roughly equal to just no value for the `action` attribute.